# How can i take screen shots from running video in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, video, screenshot

I have developed one application in iPhone which contains videos.
Now I want to take screen shots form that running video.I am not having much time for search.
Is anybody having any idea regarding this thing...I know i have asked a bit silly question but still want proper answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
- (UIImage *)thumbnailImageAtTime:(NSTimeInterval)playbackTime timeOption:(MPMovieTimeOption)option
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe this could help you:

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/2353-possible-make-screenshot-programmatically-2.html

Comment: Too much programming work I have to do here..By the way thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

To take a screenshot on iPhone press the Home and Sleep/Power buttons at the same time.

Comment: I won't be logged out?sorry to ask but having query

Comment: @user1169116 no, the video won't exit.

Comment: One more question...How can I take screen shots in some regular interval of times? I mean If I want to take Screen shots in every 5 minutes..can i do so?